# buttons on different locations

Tags: java, android, button, while-loop

Hello community i started working with android and android studio.
I a am new to all this, but i am trying.

So here is the problem,
I have 6 buttons of the same size (70x70dp)
I want this 6 buttons to be each time generated on different locations of the screen but not on the same.

I ve made it already but most of the times, some buttons goes upper the other ones.
I want somehow to restrict this.

I've tried with a while and some shitty checks and all of combinations but nothing worked so far.

```
   private void changeButtonPlace(Button button) {
    Random r = new Random();
    int newXloc = r.nextInt(getScreenWidth() - (2 * button.getLayoutParams().width));
    int newYloc = r.nextInt(getScreenHeight() - (3 * button.getLayoutParams().height));

    if (button == _button) {
        while (Math.abs(newXloc - _button1.getX()) < 10 || Math.abs(newXloc - _button2.getX()) < 10
                || Math.abs(newXloc - _button3.getX()) < 10 || Math.abs(newXloc - _button4.getX()) < 10
                || Math.abs(newXloc - _button5.getX()) < 10){
            Log.d("myTag", "KSANA UPOLOGISA");
            newXloc = r.nextInt(getScreenWidth() - (2 * button.getLayoutParams().width));
        }
        while (Math.abs(newYloc - _button1.getY()) < 10 || Math.abs(newYloc - _button2.getY()) < 10
                || Math.abs(newYloc - _button3.getY()) < 10 || Math.abs(newYloc - _button4.getY()) < 10
                || Math.abs(newYloc - _button5.getY()) < 10){
            newYloc = r.nextInt(getScreenWidth() - (2 * button.getLayoutParams().height));
        }
    } else if (button == _button1) {
        while (Math.abs(newXloc - _button.getX()) < 10 || Math.abs(newXloc - _button2.getX()) < 10
                || Math.abs(newXloc - _button3.getX()) < 10 || Math.abs(newXloc - _button4.getX()) < 10
                || Math.abs(newXloc - _button5.getX()) < 10){
            newXloc = r.nextInt(getScreenWidth() - (2 * button.getLayoutParams().width));
        }
        while (Math.abs(newYloc - _button1.getY()) < 10 || Math.abs(newYloc - _button2.getY()) < 10
                || Math.abs(newYloc - _button3.getY()) < 10 || Math.abs(newYloc - _button4.getY()) < 10
                || Math.abs(newYloc - _button5.getY()) < 10){
            newYloc = r.nextInt(getScreenWidth() - (2 * button.getLayoutParams().height));
        }
    } else if (button == _button2) {
        while (Math.abs(newXloc - _button.getX()) < 10 || Math.abs(newXloc - _button1.getX()) < 10
                || Math.abs(newXloc - _button3.getX()) < 10 || Math.abs(newXloc - _button4.getX()) < 10
                || Math.abs(newXloc - _button5.getX()) < 10){
            newXloc = r.nextInt(getScreenWidth() - (2 * button.getLayoutParams().width));
        }
        while (Math.abs(newYloc - _button1.getY()) < 10 || Math.abs(newYloc - _button2.getY()) < 10
                || Math.abs(newYloc - _button3.getY()) < 10 || Math.abs(newYloc - _button4.getY()) < 10
                || Math.abs(newYloc - _button5.getY()) < 10){
            newYloc = r.nextInt(getScreenWidth() - (2 * button.getLayoutParams().height));
        }
    } else if (button == _button3) {
        while (Math.abs(newXloc - _button.getX()) < 10 || Math.abs(newXloc - _button1.getX()) < 10
                || Math.abs(newXloc - _button2.getX()) < 10 || Math.abs(newXloc - _button4.getX()) < 10
                || Math.abs(newXloc - _button5.getX()) < 10){
            newXloc = r.nextInt(getScreenWidth() - (2 * button.getLayoutParams().width));
        }
        while (Math.abs(newYloc - _button1.getY()) < 10 || Math.abs(newYloc - _button2.getY()) < 10
                || Math.abs(newYloc - _button2.getY()) < 10 || Math.abs(newYloc - _button4.getY()) < 10
                || Math.abs(newYloc - _button5.getY()) < 10){
            newYloc = r.nextInt(getScreenWidth() - (2 * button.getLayoutParams().height));
        }
    } else if (button == _button4) {
        while (Math.abs(newXloc - _button.getX()) < 10 || Math.abs(newXloc - _button1.getX()) < 10
                || Math.abs(newXloc - _button2.getX()) < 10 || Math.abs(newXloc - _button3.getX()) < 10
                || Math.abs(newXloc - _button5.getX()) < 10){
            newXloc = r.nextInt(getScreenWidth() - (2 * button.getLayoutParams().width));
        }
        while (Math.abs(newYloc - _button1.getY()) < 10 || Math.abs(newYloc - _button2.getY()) < 10
                || Math.abs(newYloc - _button2.getY()) < 10 || Math.abs(newYloc - _button3.getY()) < 10
                || Math.abs(newYloc - _button5.getY()) < 10){
            newYloc = r.nextInt(getScreenWidth() - (2 * button.getLayoutParams().height));
        }
    } else if (button == _button5) {
        while (Math.abs(newXloc - _button.getX()) < 10 || Math.abs(newXloc - _button1.getX()) < 10
                || Math.abs(newXloc - _button2.getX()) < 10 || Math.abs(newXloc - _button4.getX()) < 10
                || Math.abs(newXloc - _button3.getX()) < 10){
            newXloc = r.nextInt(getScreenWidth() - (2 * button.getLayoutParams().width));
        }
        while (Math.abs(newYloc - _button1.getY()) < 10 || Math.abs(newYloc - _button2.getY()) < 10
                || Math.abs(newYloc - _button2.getY()) < 10 || Math.abs(newYloc - _button4.getY()) < 10
                || Math.abs(newYloc - _button3.getY()) < 10){
            newYloc = r.nextInt(getScreenWidth() - (2 * button.getLayoutParams().height));
        }
    }

    button.setX(newXloc);
    button.setY(newYloc);
}
```

Any idea?
Maybe my thought is not right, but mainly what i want, is each time the 6 buttons to be on different place.

Comment: This looks way too complicated. Anyhow, why don't you just store the coords of the existing buttons and reroll as long as the coords intersect?

Comment: thanks for your fast reply, maybe i can store on each intersect the X,Y locs in a array and then as you said each time check if its the same, but if i am not wrong, button location is specifically 1 coordinary, which for example can be 500,500 if the code generates 501,501 will be a problem also.

Comment: so maybe, i need to check plus 70 dp each time for both dimensions

Answer (score 0):

As far as I am concerned your question is related to Intent. For that you must create each of the six buttons in six new activities and than paste this code

```
 public void onClick(View view) {
                        Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, sushi.class);
                        startActivity(i);
                    }
```

In place of sushi.class you must provide the .class name of the new activity.

Comment: maybe i didnt exaplain well, my questions

Comment: heres what i wanted to make http://prntscr.com/axjlmy 
and here is how some times comes http://prntscr.com/axjm14

Comment: you can do this by Intent also. Create the first screenshot as one activity and second screenshot as another activity an onClick you can show the second activity.

Comment: i ve overcome this problem already using the setOnTouchListener on the main layout of the activity, my problem is that the buttons once are generated are not on the right place, as you can see on the images, some buttons goes upper the others, check the image http://prntscr.com/axjudi

thanks for your reply anyway